# Conversion of Byte array to double on receiving of integer values from modbus simulator?

Tags: java, casting, nio, modbus

Anyone knows about modbus simulator, I am stucked in converting the values. I am using wimpi modbus api to connect to the device and read and write register values. So I am having a modbus simulator where I got some values in each register based on that one register is of 2 bytes. so i am having 4 register values together give me one measurement value. So using wimpi readregister i am getting integer values for particular register. I have voltage measurement as (16492 35578 10726 22350). These 4 register values makes one double values. So the thing i need is to convert these 4 integer values to a single double value for which modbusutil.registersToDouble() method is available which accepts byte array values.

If anyone help me out for the conversion will be appreciable.

Right now i am trying like this :

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 16492,(byte) 35578,(byte) 10726,(byte) 22350};
        Double d = ModbusUtil.registersToDouble(bytes);
System.out.println(d);
```

it is throwing exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at net.wimpi.modbus.util.ModbusUtil.registersToDouble(ModbusUtil.java:343)
```

Please let me know if anybody did the conversion of integer values received from registers to double.

I am getting response values using :

```
ReadInputRegistersResponse registersResponse = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) this.modbusTCPTransaction.getResponse();

registersResponse.getRegister(1).getValue();
registersResponse.getRegister(2).getValue();
registersResponse.getRegister(3).getValue();
registersResponse.getRegister(4).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/api/net/wimpi/modbus/util/ModbusUtil.html):

> registersToDouble
>
> public static final double registersToDouble(byte[] bytes)
>
> Converts a byte[8] binary double value into a double primitive.
>
> Parameters:
>
> bytes - a byte[8] to be converted.
>
> Returns:
>
> a double value.

So I guess you need to have an array of 8 elements.

Moreover from the [Oracle Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> **byte**: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)

So I think you'll lose the information about your measurement converting `35578` fo `byte`. It gives: `-6` and this is not what you're probably need.

Comment: can you help me out Xeon coz our device is configured to send 4 register values only for a single measurement and in device it is in hex form. How to make this conversion successful without loosing data....any reference